# How to download in excel/csv all the FDA drug enforcements available?

Tags: data-request, drugs

[The openFDA drug enforcement reports API](https://open.fda.gov/drug/enforcement/reference/) download returns results in one large JSON file.

Unfortunately I have no experience in parsing/programming JSON and I need the drug enforcements data in Excel/CSV format (2004-present as far as I know).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What data are you talking about? Please provide a link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I really appreciate.  I want to get these data on drug enforcments:              https://open.fda.gov/drug/enforcement/reference/

Comment: I have edited your question to exactly describe the issue. Please take some time next time to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the JSON file and open it with a Json to CSV converter like http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

You will get [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xi8xg4q53u28k7/json-to_csv.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is that the JSTON file that is downloadable contains only 2012-2017 records. However OpenFDA says that  "The openFDA drug enforcement reports API returns data from the FDA Recall Enterprise System (RES)... Currently, this data covers publically releasable records from 2004-present". And I am not able to  run openFDA API queries to retrieve the data starting from 2004. Thanks again for help.

Comment: Their [database](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/ires/index.cfm#tabNav_advancedSearch) does not allow you to go back before 2012, and their APIs neither. You may want to check if someone has this data or ask the US Food & Drug Administration directly.

Comment: I see. I will probably make a Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) request. Thanks for help. https://www.fda.gov/RegulatoryInformation/FOI/HowtoMakeaFOIARequest/default.htm